# NSIS - js-files decompression takes very long

Tags: javascript, windows, nsis

I created an installer (with nsis) which installs a plugin for adobe illustrator. Since now everything worked fine, but when I changed some paths of my files, the installer takes about 7 minutes (compared to 1 minute before - when everything worked fine).

As I took a closer look to the installing process I found out, that the decompression of ".js"-files takes very long, and there are a lot of them.
Afterwards I tried to install one of the old versions, which where fast enough, but now also these installers take about 7 minutes.

So I think that somehow the new installer changed something on the machine that has something to do with the decompression of js-files.

Furthermore I recognized that on my machine, where I'm developing, I do not faces this issue. Only on other Windows machines, where I try to install my plugin.

I also tried to use different compression methods, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same minute as I posted this question, I found the answer. My antivirus (trend micro, security agent) made the installation slow. When I deactivate it, installation runs fast enough.

Any idea how to make the installation faster with activated antivirus? Or is there no way?

Comment: AV software needs to read everything you write and then look it up in a database and maybe even check online. A SSD will make the system faster if you write many small files.